# Game of Life:- need help in implementing SOLID principles in Game of life

Tags: java, eclipse, conways-game-of-life

Hi I am trying to execute game of life program by applying principles such open and close, single responsibility principle,liskov substitution principle,Interface segregation principle and dependency inversion principle. But I am stuck and cannot think where exactly principles should I apply. I am newbie in this if anyone know can someone please help me to understand how to proceed or how to apply it I would really appreciate it.Thank you in advance.
I am uploading certain portion of code as an examples where this principles should be applied.

Abstractgame stratedgy

```
public abstract class AbstractGameStratedgy implements GameStratedy {

    private Rule [] rules; 

    @Override
    public void setRules(Rule[] rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
    }

    @Override
    public Rule[] getRules() {
        return rules;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Cell> findNeighbours(Cell cell,Set<Cell> liveCells)
    {
        HashSet<Cell> neighbours=new HashSet<Cell>(); 

        int x=cell.getX();
        int y=cell.getY();
        Cell tempCell;
        for(int i=x-1;i<=x+1;i++)
        {
            if(i<0) continue;

            for(int j=y-1;j<=y+1;j++)
            {
                if(j<0) continue;

                tempCell=new Cell(i, j);
                if(liveCells.contains(tempCell))
                {
                    tempCell.setState(State.LIVE);
                }
                neighbours.add(tempCell);
            }
        }

        return neighbours;
    }
}
```

Cell

```
public class Cell {

    private final int x,y;
    private State state;

    public Cell(int x,int y)
    {
        this(x,y,State.DEAD);
    }

    public Cell(int x,int y,State state)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Cell other = (Cell) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public Cell createCopy() {
        return new Cell(x,y,state);
    }

}
```

RuleRunner

```
public class RuleRunner {

    private GameStratedy gameStratedy;

    public RuleRunner(GameStratedy gameStratedy)
    {
        this.gameStratedy = gameStratedy;
    }


    public Set<Cell> applyRules(Set<Cell> liveCells) {
        HashSet<Cell> nextGeneration=new HashSet<Cell>(); 

        Set<Cell> neighbouringCells;
        for(Cell cellFromCurrentGeneration: liveCells)
        {
            processCell(cellFromCurrentGeneration,liveCells,nextGeneration);

            neighbouringCells=gameStratedy.findNeighbours(cellFromCurrentGeneration, liveCells);

            for(Cell neighbouringCell:neighbouringCells)
            {
                processCell(neighbouringCell,liveCells,nextGeneration);
            }
        }

        return filterDead(nextGeneration);
    }

    private Set<Cell> filterDead(HashSet<Cell> nextGeneration) {
        Iterator<Cell> iterator = nextGeneration.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            if(State.DEAD.equals(iterator.next().getState()))
            {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        return nextGeneration;
    }


    private void processCell(Cell cell,Set<Cell> currentGeneration,Set<Cell> nextGeneration)
    {
        if(nextGeneration.contains(cell)) return; // already processed

        cell=cell.createCopy();

        State nextState=cell.getState();
        for(Rule rule:gameStratedy.getRules())
        {
            nextState=rule.nextState(cell.getState(), findLiveNeighbourCount(cell, currentGeneration));

            if(!cell.getState().equals(nextState))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        cell.setState(nextState);
        nextGeneration.add(cell);
    }



    private int findLiveNeighbourCount(Cell cell,Set<Cell> liveCells)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(Cell c:gameStratedy.findNeighbours(cell, liveCells))
        {
            if(State.LIVE.equals(c.getState())) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had earlier shared only the links to README.md file of my Github repository of my implementation and there was a genuine concern expressed to me by the moderators, what if the pages behind the links are removed? I am providing an answer, which I hope is helpful in understanding the solution without having to refer to my README.md file or the code.

This question is from a year ago. You likely would have already figured out the SOLID principles. Since, I have recently solved Conway's Game of Life in PHP OOP and applied the SOLID design principles with the objective of sharing my understanding of the principles with my colleagues at work, I am sharing my approach to solving this problem here on stackoverflow as an answer to this question, which is so far unanswered. I hope this is helpful to all who arrive here wanting to wrap their heads around SOLID principles specifically by practicing it on Conway's Game of Life problem.

Below was my thought progression on what classes need to be there:

Step 1: I started out with obvious classes from the problem statement, which are the *Board* and *Cell*, the board being composed of many cells.

Step 2: On applying **Single Responsibility Principle**, a class should have a single responsibility and only one reason to change, to the *Board* and the *Cell* I broke these two classes down into these classes:

- *Board* (for maintaining board dimensions and active cell locations, and the getNeighbourCount() method)
- *BoardRenderer* (for drawing the board on the medium)
- *BoardPersister* (for persisting, i.e. saving the board layout out of memory to a persistent storage like MySQL between steps)
- *BoardInitializer* (for initial arrangement of live cells on the board at the start of game)
- For cells I needed only *CellRenderer*, because at this point I began
  realizing my Cell class had no other work to do but to be rendered
  (active cell one way, inactive cell another way). It is the board
  which will have the knowledge of its dimensions and the location of
  active cells (and therefore also the location of inactive cells). I
  do not require the *Cell* class.

Step 3: Next from my understanding of what **Open/Close and Dependency Inversion principles** are, which respectively state, software entities should be open for extension but closed for modification and one should depend upon abstractions and not upon concretions (source Wikipedia), I converted *BoardInitializer*, *BoardRenderer*, *BoardPersister*, *CellRenderer* from classes to interfaces so that I can build new classes and use them by simply replacing existing classes. These new classes only need to implement their respective interfaces.

At this stage I realized and I also needed a game controller. So I added a *GameController* abstract class with newGame() and advanceGame() methods and a *GameRenderer* interface to primarily render the game controls. I also converted *Board* into an abstract class to be able to have two types of boards: *EdgesWrappedBoard* and *BoundedBoard*. *GameRenderer* would call *BoardRenderer*, which in turn would make use of *CellRenderer* for painting active and inactive cells.

So, now we have these classes,

#### Abstract Classes:

- *Board*
- *GameController*

#### Classes extending abstract classes:

- *EdgesWrappedBoard* (extends *Board*)
- *BoundedBoard* (extends *Board*)
- *HTMLGameController* (extends *GameController*)
- *ConsoleGameController* (extends *GameController*)

#### Interfaces:

- *GameRenderer*
- *BoardRenderer*
- *CellRenderer*
- *BoardInitializer*
- *BoardPersister*

#### Classes implementing interfaces:

- *HTMLGameRenderer* (implements *GameRenderer*)
- *ConsoleGameRenderer* (implements *GameRenderer*)
- *HTMLBoardRenderer* (implements *BoardRenderer*)
- *ConsoleBoardRenderer* (implements *BoardRenderer*)
- *HTMLCellRenderer* (implements *CellRenderer*)
- *ConsoleCellRenderer* (implements *CellRenderer*)
- *RandomBoardInitializer* (implements *BoardInitializer*)
- *Test1BoardInitializer* (implements *BoardInitializer*)
- *Test2BoardInitializer* (implements *BoardInitializer*)
- *FileBoardPersister* (implements *BoardPersister*)
- *MySQLBoardPersister* (implements *BoardPersister*)

Step 4: Finally, I checked for any violation of **Liskov's Subsitution Principle** or **Interface Segregation Principle**. There were none. These principles respectively are:
Objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program.
Many client-specific interfaces are better than one general-purpose interface.

**Note:** From the very beginning, to bring out Dependency Inversion and Open/Close principles I set out to have both Web (HTML) and Console interfaces, and be able to persist to both file or database.

If you are interested in seeing my thought progression as class diagrams, you can refer to the README.md file of my [implementation of Game of Life](https://github.com/skgchn/conways-game-of-life-oop-solid) shared on GitHub. There would be other solutions as well. My objective was to best communicate my understanding of SOLID principles to my colleagues at work so that we together can implement better maintainability in our OOP PHP code.